# unexpected T_FUNCTION error when using "function (array $matches)"

Tags: php, syntax-error

Hi I'm using the following code but I'm getting an "unexpected T_FUNCTION" syntax error for the second line. Any suggestions?

```
preg_replace_callback("/\\[LINK\=(.*?)\\\](.*?)\\[\/LINK\\]/is",
function (array $matches) {
    if (filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return '<a href="'.
            htmlspecialchars($matches[1], ENT_QUOTES).
            '" target="_blank">'.
            htmlspecialchars($matches[2])."</a>";
    else
        return "INVALID MARKUP";
}, $text);
```

Comment: Does your version of PHP support closures?

Comment: @Mike B. I use PHP 5.2 so I guess not.

Comment: You need at least php 5.3: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That happens when your PHP is older than 5.3. Anonymous function support wasn't available until 5.3, so PHP won't recognize function signatures passed as parameters like that.

You'll have to create a function the traditional way, and pass its name instead (I use `link_code()` for example):

```
function link_code(array $matches) {
    if (filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return '<a href="'.
            htmlspecialchars($matches[1], ENT_QUOTES).
            '" target="_blank">'.
            htmlspecialchars($matches[2])."</a>";
    else
        return "INVALID MARKUP";
}

preg_replace_callback("/\\[LINK\=(.*?)\\\](.*?)\\[\/LINK\\]/is", 'link_code', $text);
```

Also, `array $matches` is not a problem because type hinting for arrays is supported in PHP 5.2.