# Recursively search directories and list the x newest files (based on creation date on server)

Tags: php, file, recursion, directory

Ok, I don't fully understand what I'm doing here, so I thought I'd get some feedback on my code.

Trying to recursively search through specific folders on my server, and return the 30 newest *.jpg images that were added (with full filepath).

At the moment my current code gives me (I'm assuming) timestamps (they each look like a string of 10 numbers), and actually I seem to only be getting 22 out of the full 30 I was expecting. I saw another post using `directoryIteratorIterator`, but I'm not able to upgrade my PHP version for my server and I can't find a lot of clear documentation on that.

Hoping someone can steer me in the right direction on this.

```
<?php
function get30Latest(){
    $files = array();
    foreach (glob("*/*.jpg") as $filename) {  //I assume "*/*.jpg" would start from the root of the server and go through each directory looking for a match to *.jpg and add to $files array
        $files[$filename] = filemtime($filename);
    }
    arsort($files); //I may not need this since I'm looking to sort by earliest to latest (among the 30 newest images)

    $newest = array_slice($files, 0, 29);  //This should be the first 30 I believe.

    foreach ($newest as $file){ //Assuming I would loop through the array and display the full paths of these 30 images
        echo $file . "</br>"; //Returns something similar to "1451186291, 1451186290, 1451186290, etc..."
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The recursive directory iterator starts at `PHP v5` so unless you have `v4.x` you can do that method: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php The first contributor notes on that page may be what you need to do the iteration and regex for `jpg`.

Comment: Ok, tried the first contributor's note.  Works, so I guess I have at least v5 PHP.  Things are going alright, however i'm only seeing "array" printed, and not the file path.  Here's where I'm at so far:

`function get30Latest(){
 $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./');
 $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
 $regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.jpg$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

 $count = 1;
 foreach($regex as $file){
  echo $count . ":" . " " . $file . "</br>";
  $count++;
 }
}
`

Comment: So you see the paths for each file? Like `/server/root/html/webroot/images/file.jpg`?

Comment: No, I'm seeing "1: array, 2: array, 3: array...."

Comment: Oh yeah I see, that saves to an array so in your case: `echo $count . ":" . " " . $file[0] . "</br>";`

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Yeah.  So I'm seeing my files now in their full path.  Now what is the proper way to compare these and find the latest 30 based on creation date (or mod date since I'm not sure if most servers save creation date)?  Is there a function I can run to sort by creation date and then just take the first 30 from the resulting array?

Comment: I will write an answer and contain the logic. You can use what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on a good way. This should work for you:

First of all we create a [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) which we pass to our [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) so we have an iterator to iterate recursively through all files of your specified path. We filter everything expect `*.jpg` files out with a [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.regexiterator.php).

Now we can convert the iterator into an array with [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php), so we can sort the array as we want to. Which we do with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) combined with [`filectime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) so we compare the creation date of the files and sort it by that.

At the end we can just slice the 30 newest files with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and we are done. Loop through the files and display them.

Code:

```
<?php

    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("your/path"));
    $rgIt = new RegexIterator($it, "/^.+\.jpg$/i");

    $files = iterator_to_array($rgIt);

    usort($files, function($a, $b){
      if(filectime($a) == filectime($b))
        return 0;
      return filectime($a) > filectime($b) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $files = array_slice($files, 0 , 30);

    foreach($files as $v)
      echo $v . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Comment: Close.  However I'm getting a syntax error at line 8 (at usort).  Its saying unexpected T_FUNCTION, so I'm wondering if the way you're passing function like that is not supported in the version of PHP I have on my server, per this post I just dug up:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657357/unexpected-t-function-error-when-using-function-array-matches)

Comment: @dotcommer Yes, it is a PHP version thing. anonymous functions only work with PHP >= 5.3 (`echo PHP_VERSION;`). Just declare the function as normal function, give it a name, and pass the name as second argument to `usort()`

Comment: Ok, would that just be something like `function compareFileCTime($a, $b){
 if(filectime($a) == filectime($b))
        return 0;
    return filectime($a) > filectime($b) ? -1 : 1;
}`

And then `usort($files, compareFileCTime())`?

Comment: @dotcommer Almost, just `usort($files, compareFileCTime())` -> `usort($files, "compareFileCTime");`

Comment: Ah!  So close.  Ok, that gets me what I want!  Thank you Rizier!  Would you mind adding to your answer with the alternative for anyone else who doesn't have PHP 5.3+?  Then I'll mark is as the answer to this question.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, one more question:  Can I pass an array of directories to `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`?  If I know of only a couple folders that should be looked at for this function, it would probably be faster to do that than scan the whole site.

Comment: Also, had a quick chat with my web host, and the flipped a switch to 5.4.43.  Your previous answer also works for me now!

Comment: @dotcommer 1) I won't include the code for PHP 5.3, since it's not supported anymore: http://php.net/supported-versions.php 2) Also if you have single directories which you want to go through you can either use `glob()` and `array_merge()` all files from each folder together, which you then can filter with `preg_grep()` and then sort the array again as in my answer. OR if you want to do it with iterators you can create a normal `DirectoryIterator` with `AppendIterator` to append each directory to the same iterator, then you can convert it as in my answer and go from there.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you very much for your help.  Same to @Rasclatt.  You guys have been great and patient with me while I stumble through this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99249/discussion-between-dotcommer-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may want to do is keep you function more general, incase you want to use it's function(s) for other uses or just plain change it. You won't have to then create a `get10Latest()` or `get25Latest()`, etc. This is just a simple class that contains all the script that you need to fetch and return. Use what you want from it, the methods are in order of use, so you could just take out the guts of the methods to create one big function:

```
class   FetchImages
    {
        private $count  =   30;
        private $arr    =   array();
        private $regex  =   '';
        public  function __construct($filter = array('jpg'))
            {
                // This will create a simple regex from the array of file types ($filter)
                $this->regex    =   '.+\.'.implode('|.+\.',$filter);
            }

        public  function getImgs($dir = './')
            {
                // Borrowed from contributor notes from the RecursiveDirectoryIterator page
                $regex      =   new RegexIterator(
                                new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)),
                                '/^'.$this->regex.'$/i',
                                RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
                // Loop and assign datetimes as keys,
                // You don't need date() but it's more readable for troubleshooting
                foreach($regex as $file)
                    $this->arr[date('YmdHis',filemtime($file[0]))][]    =   $file[0];
                // return the object for method chaining
                return $this;
            }

        public  function setMax($max = 30)
            {
                // This will allow for different returned values
                $this->count    =   $max;
                // Return for method chaining
                return $this;
            }

        public  function getResults($root = false)
            {
                if(empty($this->arr))
                    return false;
                // Set default container
                $new    =   array();
                // Depending on your version, you may not have the "SORT_NATURAL"
                // This is what will sort the files from newest to oldest
                // I have not accounted for empty->Will draw error(s) if not array
                krsort($this->arr,SORT_NATURAL);
                // Loop through storage array and make a new storage
                // with single paths
                foreach($this->arr as $timestamp => $files) {
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
                        $new[]  =   (!empty($root))? str_replace($root,"",$files[$i]) : $files[$i];
                }
                // Return the results
                return (!$this->count)? $new : array_slice($new,0,$this->count);
            }
    }

// Create new instance. I am allowing for multiple look-up
$getImg =   new FetchImages(array("jpg","jpeg","png"));
// Get the results from my core folder
$count  =   $getImg ->getImgs(__DIR__.'/core/')
                    // Sets the extraction limit "false" will return all
                    ->setMax(30)
                    // This will strip off the long path
                    ->getResults(__DIR__);

print_r($count);
```

Comment: Ok, bear with me here.  I'm going to reply as an answer so you can see how I'm going about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really need a giant, flexible class of functions.  This function will always output the 30 latest images.  If I'm understanding correctly, you're assigning a timestamp as a key to each file in the array, and then sorting by the key using krsort?  I'm trying to pull out just those pieces in order to get an array of files with timestamps, sorted from latest to oldest, and then slice the array to just the first 30.  Here's just a quick attempt as a talking point (not complete by any means).  At the moment its outputting only one file several hundred times:

```
<?php
function get30Latest(){
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./');
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
    $regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.jpg$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

    foreach($regex as $file){
        $tmp->arr[date('YmdHis',filemtime($file[0]))][] = $file[0];
        krsort($tmp->arr,SORT_NATURAL);

        foreach($tmp->arr as $timestamp => $files) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
                $new[] = (!empty($root))? str_replace($root,"",$files[$i]) : $files[$i];

            echo $new[0] . "</br>";  //this is just for debugging so I can see what files
                                     //are showing up.  Ideally this will be the array I'll
                                     //pull the first 30 from and then send them off to a
                                     //thumbnail creation function
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah that looks about right from what I made, does yours work fine?

Comment: No, unfortunately.  This code currently prints out a long list of the same image, "Image01.jpg, image01.jpg, image01.jpg...."

Comment: You are missing the `array_slice()` to trim the `$new`.