# Use correct path to display latest uploaded images

Tags: php, recursiveiterator

I built a gallery script on my own and on my wordpress blog I successfully displayed 12 images that are uploading through various sub-directories of that gallery.
However, when checking the single post page, the code fails because instead of linking to https://your-domain.com/gallery/... it links to the post permalink+/gallery/.....

This is the code I am using (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34511956/23556208)

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./gallery"));
    $rgIt = new RegexIterator($it, "/^.+\.jpg$/i");

    $files = iterator_to_array($rgIt);

    usort($files, function($a, $b){
      if(filectime($a) == filectime($b))
        return 0;
      return filectime($a) > filectime($b) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $files = array_slice($files, 0 , 12);

    foreach($files as $v){
        echo "<a href='".$v."' target='_blank'><img src='". $v ."' /></a>";
    }
```

How can I implement the URL so on the single page they go to that **https://your-domain.com/gallery** exclusively and not to the post permalink first?

Comment: a URL that starts with a `/` relates to the top level domain.  so you should probably `<a href='/".$v."' ...>`

Comment: @ITgoldman that did the trick for linkinging, indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fixes to correct on my code were:

1. removing the `./` from RecursiveDirectoryIterator

   `new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('gallery')`
2. Add a `/` for both link and image

   `<a href='/". $v ."' target='_blank'><img src='/". $v ."' /></a>`